# Incompatible pointer type assigning to 'ViewController'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, incompatibility

I have a ViewController class (maybe I shouldn't have named that class that way ?)

Why do I have a warning

> Incompatible pointer type assigning to 'ViewController' from
>   'UIViewController' in AppDelegate

Update:

at this line

```
self.viewController = [[[myPlugin alloc] getPluginViewController] autorelease];
```

in AppDelegate.h I have

```
@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

in myPlugin I have

```
-(ViewController*) getPluginViewController {
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    return self.viewController;
```

In ViewController I have

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't have named the class that.

Comment: where you have defined viewController as property, can you add that code?

Comment: otherwise if you are keen to remove this warning there is a work around - self.viewController = (ViewController *) [[[myPlugin alloc] getPluginViewController] autorelease];

Comment: Can you add the definition of you ViewController class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewController property in your app delegate probably has type `UIViewController*` and you are trying to assign an object of type `ViewController*` to it.  Probably your ViewController class needs to inherit from UIViewController.

There are many other problems with your code:

```
self.viewController = [[[myPlugin alloc] getPluginViewController] autorelease];
```

Ignoring the assignment, the first message sent to an object straight after it has been allocated should be an init message by convention.  99.99% of programmers will automatically assume this is a horrendous bug in your code whether or not it is a horrendous bug.  You should stick to the conventions.

Also, if `getPluginViewController` abides by the memory management rules, you do not own the object it returns, so you **must not** autorelease it.

```
-(ViewController*) getPluginViewController {
     self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     return self.viewController;
}
```

In itself, this is kind of OK.  In Objective-C, by convention, a method beginning with "get" is for methods that return values in pointer parameters.  However, putting it together with where you call it there are several problems:

- the original allocated ViewController leaks because this method returns a pointer to a different object
- the original allocated ViewController is never initialised
- the returned ViewController is autoreleased twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot I now see my error - I have never programmed in C so jumping directly to Objective C is hard for me :)

Comment: @user310291: yes it can be a bit of a steep learning curve, but Objective-C is a nice language once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention at double allocating.

First time you allocating with `[myPlugin alloc]` and calling `getPluginViewController`.
But in `getPluginViewController` you allocate and initialize new `ViewController` and return it.

Comment: I should precise the context for me: myPlugin class is one thing and myPluginViewController does return a suview of the plugin which has no main view by itsef. In that case is there still something wrong according to you ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the reference of `ViewController` and other classes which you think have problem.

Go to the finder and add again those classes by unchecking '-copy' if needed.

Clean the project from product menu and run.